# What is the cause of delay sending SMTP via phpmailer.class?

Tags: php, email, server, smtp, phpmailer

My scripts using **phpmailer class** to send out emails via **SMTP auth**.
Sometimes I have delays (up to 20 minutes); sometimes the mail is sent out immediately.

Who is responsible for the delay? The provider of the Mailserver or the provider where my PHP script runs?

(...In the past I've used **php mail()** function and run in the same delay problems. This is why I have changed to phpmailer class.)

Comment: mailservers have queues. they will accept the mail at almost any rate, then queue it for sending. if you have access to the command line you can get information from the mail-server on what its doing, how many mails are queued up etc. if your on a shared host its not just your email but there could be thousands of sites using one mail-server. anlaysys of the mail headers from a sent email will tell you how much time the email spent on each mail server so exactly where the delay occurred.

Comment: Email is not an immediate delivery protocol; it's store-and-forward, and many services (Yahoo springs to mind) insert delays in the delivery chain for various reasons.

Comment: Typically it is the _receiving_ side of the mail servers that cause issues when being down or under streass.

Comment: A good thing to start is to take a look at the code of an email message you receive. In the headers you can typically a finger print of each server the message went over along with  time stamps...

Answer (score 0):

The post says "Sometimes" - so it would appear the problem is with the server that is processing your emails.

It may not be a real problem so much as a workload.

One way to test this theory is to use a different mail server and see if the problem persists.

Comment: And how should the OP "use a different mail server" for the receiving side?

Comment: Sorry, but this is not an answer. It should have been a comment since it only provides some general aspects, but not a solution. It does not even try to do so.

Comment: And, btw, you did not propose a "theory", but a simple proposition. A theory is something completely different, of much more profound nature.